UUserWidget pure c++ create,viewport is invisible
use pure c++ create a c++ UUserWidget ,cant show in Viewport!
1.when I use c++ create,it didn't show, but anything is work,like call this class function.
I have been check any Visibililty ,bEnable or any state of this widget,all is fine!
            UCanvasWidget* Instance = CreateWidget<UCanvasWidget>(World, UCanvasWidget::StaticClass(), FName("1.UUserWidget"));
            Instance->RootPanel = Instance->WidgetTree->ConstructWidget<UCanvasPanel>(UCanvasPanel::StaticClass(),FName("2.CanvasPanel"));
            UImage* Image = Instance->WidgetTree->ConstructWidget<UImage>(UImage::StaticClass(),FName("3.UImage"));
            Instance->RootPanel->AddChild(Image);
            Instance->WidgetTree->RootWidget = Instance->RootPanel;
            Instance->AddToViewport();

2.I use the blueprint to inherit my class :UCanvasWidget:UUserWidget,it can show uimage graphic or added UWidget element, normally.
final:i guess its a problem between bp and c++,bp has solve some other invisible step to make it!
any idea,my genius friend?

solve it.
UUserWidget must override UUserWidget::RebuildWidget()
try to add this:
this->WidgetTree->RootWidget =  this->WidgetTree->ConstructWidget<UCanvasPanel>(UCanvasPanel::StaticClass());

you must set a rootwidget inside,otherwise it will automatic create a empty content
    // Add the first component to the root of the widget surface.
    TSharedRef<SWidget> UserRootWidget = WidgetTree->RootWidget ? WidgetTree->RootWidget->TakeWidget() : TSharedRef<SWidget>(SNew(SSpacer));

